# GET HTTPS не действующий протокол c#

Tags: c#, ssl, https

Требуется выполнить простой GET запрос к сайту по HTTPS протоколу, даже если тот не действующий. Вот пример [сайта](https://www.christopherleeco.com).

```
Host = "https://www.christopherleeco.com";
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Host);
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string StausCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readerStream = new StreamReader(resStream);
string responseStream = readerStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Получаю исключение: `System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`.
Хотя если вместо этого "хоста" вставить `https://www.google.com`, то запрос проходит нормально.

Comment: Порт проверяли?

Comment: @artyom "https://" и так подразумевает 443 порт, если сделать так `Host = "https://www.christopherleeco.com:443";` то ничего не меняется

Comment: Сертификат невалиден, соединение и не устанавливается.

Comment: @monk да понятно, что он не валиден. Это нужно проигнорировать и все равно получить содержимое страницы. Google  Chrome же открывает его по 443, после предупреждения.

Comment: Пробовали получить детали, как описано на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317771/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel ?

Comment: @artyom Вот лог (детали) http://pastebin.com/R0GcRVD2. Код взят из ответа ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Для игнора ошибок общая практика:

```
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Итого, у меня вполне работает вариант:

```
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
  var data = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.christopherleeco.com");
```

Comment: С HttpWebRequest'ом этот вариант не работает. Можно ли как-то через ваш метод узнать Status Code страницы ? (301 404 403 500 ... )

Comment: Обнаружил что ваш пример у меня не работает, также выдает исключение `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`, я работаю в `VS Express 2013 for Desktop` `Windows 7 32bit`

Comment: @user217683 а какая версия dotNet используется? Рекомендую минимум 4.5, на версиях ниже может отличаться поведение.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то в проекте используется .NET Framework 4.5