# Как добавить сертификат?

Tags: c#, xnet

Приветствую! Работаю с библиотекой **xNet**. При попытке отправить **POST** запрос, никакого положительного результата я не получаю, скорее всего нужно для работы добавить сертификат данного сайта. Как это сделать? Мой кусок кода с отправкой пост запроса.

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
                {
                    HttpResponse response;
```

`` request.Proxy = Helper.GetProxy(proxyIndex);

                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
                request.Referer = @"https://domain.com";
                request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.RandomUserAgent();
                string content = request.Get("https://domain.com").ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(content);


                response = request.Post("URL POST", "VALUE POST");` ``

Comment: Update: Сертификат находится у меня в хранилище. Как нибудь его задействовать можно? или получить автоматически от сайта ? Главное чтобы при **POST** запросе он уже работал.

Comment: М.б. игнорировать его? Как  сделали на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556025

Comment: @Artyom лучше бы конечно добавить